# Passing date to shell script from crontab

Tags: shell, ubuntu-12.04, cron

Suppose I have the following shell script named test.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 $2
```

I have the following command on my crontab.

```
date=`date --date="next day" +"%Y-%m-%d"`
40 12 * * * ~/test.sh 1 $date
```

The email I receive is the following.

```
1 `date
```

Why is test.sh not echoing the next day? When I pass $date to the command line it prints what I want it to as follows.

```
./test.sh 1 $date
1 2013-09-13
```

Why is it different, and how do I instruct the crontab to pass into test.sh the next day?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can run commands in a crontab file. Why not just get the date on the script itself?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the `%` character in the crontab entry. In order to use `%`, you'll have to escape it. The following entry worked for me

```
# ~/test.sh 1 $(date --date="next day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
40 12 * * * ~/test.sh 1 $(date --date="next day" +"\%Y-\%m-\%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it worked fine for me, on Fedora 18.

You could try a couple of alternatives:

```
date=$(date --date="next day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
40 12 * * * ~/test.sh 1 $date
```

Or

```
40 12 * * * ~/test.sh 1 `date --date="next day" +"%Y-%m-%d"`
```

Or

```
40 12 * * * ~/test.sh 1 $(date --date="next day" +"%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: This is strange. None of these worked for me. The first one produces `1 $(date`. The second and third one both produce `/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`"'` and `/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`.

Comment: @idealistikz That *is* strange. What happens if you enclose it in quotes, such as: `date="$(date --date='next day' +'%Y-%m-%d')"`? Or escape the spaces: `date=$(date\ --date="next day"\ +"%Y-%m-%d")`?